# Are JSSE/JCA/JCE packages threadsafe?

Tags: java, jsse

I want to know whether the classes from the JSSE/JCE/JCA package like KeyManager, TrustManager, KeyStore etc are thread-safe in Java or they need to be made thread-safe.

Comment: There are no encryption keys in a JKS file. There is a private key and a public key wrapped in a certificate. These are not used for encryption. You don't need to use any of the classes you mention: you only need the KeyStore class. You certainly shouldn't be writing anything that will expose the private key over the Web.

Comment: @EJP, thanks for answer & sorry for question being a bit ambiguous. Yes, the jks file contains the public/private key & they could be used for encryption purpose. Basically my application is going sending the public keys from the .jks file. I asked the question for whole of the JSSE package because somewhere I will be using them. Editing question to make it more contextual.

Comment: Search for the words "thread" or "concurrently" in the Java Platform, Standard Edition Security Developer’s Guide r14, quoting an example: _Most of the classes and interfaces in the CertPath API are not thread-safe. However, there are some exceptions, which will be noted in this guide and in the API specification._.